# Failed to collect coverage from xxx.vue jest

Tags: jestjs

I got this log when I run `yarn test`.
I've tried to delete node_modules, reinstall all the dependencies and run `yarn test --no-cache`, but it doesn't work.

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ jest --coverage
 PASS  __test__/src/App.test.ts
  √ test1 (2 ms)

Running coverage on untested files...Failed to collect coverage from D:\svn-frontend-admin\src\App.vue
ERROR: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 6179
STACK: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 6179
```

These are my config files

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ......

  preset: 'ts-jest',
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,ts,vue}', 'src/*.{ts,vue}'],
  coverageReporters: ['clover'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': require.resolve('jest-transform-stub'),
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/.*)|(vue/dist/.*))'
  ],

  ......
};
```

Comment: Which jest version are you using? Try adding collectCoveragePathIgnore config which you don't want to collect coverage from.

Comment: Hahah, I've solved this problem.But I did not find out why this problem exited. I revert all the files I've edited and try again under the guide of official document, it magically works!